# Model fields not being created in the database

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a project application, in which the users are going to be designated tasks and able to make comments to the project in general. After struggling with no fields fields from the comment model, I am now faced with only one field. So far I have not been able to sort out why this is happening. Any input or clues on where to look for information would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=50,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    project_owner2 = models.ForeignKey(Entity, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default='916 075 855', #dette er bruker sin organisasjon
        )

    direction = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    title = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=50,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    scope = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='Scope', # denne må få nytt navn
        help_text='Her skal du beskrive prosjektets omfang',
        max_length=2000,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    project_status_choices = (
        ('PLANNED', 'Planned'),
        ('ACTIVE', 'Active'),
        ('ON_HOLD', 'On hold'),
        ('COMPLETED', 'Completed'),
        ('CANCELLED', 'Cancelled'),
    )

    project_create = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Project creation date',
        help_text='When the project was initiated',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    project_start = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Project start date',
        help_text='Her skal du beskrive prosjektet',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    project_end = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Project end date',
        help_text='Originaly end date',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title`


class ProjectComment(models.Model):
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, editable=False),
comment = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False),
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.project} {0.pub_date} {0.user}'
        return template.format(self)`
```

The comment model was created with the initial migration, but contained no fields back then - these have been added later. I have tried to delete all references to the comment model in the migrations and dropped the table before recreating it, resulting in a single field being added.[Database tables and dependencies after recreating the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNZVd.png)

The initial migration file looks lie this:

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.6 on 2023-03-19 08:35

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Project',
            fields=[
                ('project_id', models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)),
                ('purpose', models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, verbose_name='Purpose')),
                ('scope', models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=2000, null=True, verbose_name='Scope')),
                ('project_start', models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Project start date')),
                ('project_end', models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Project end date')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ProjectComment',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

** Update**
I just created a new model *Comment* based on the old one:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    publication_date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, editable=False),
    comment_field = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False),
    user = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False),

    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.project} {0.pub_date} {0.user}'
        return template.format(self)
```

And this is what happened when migrating:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('projects', '0008_alter_departementalroles_options_and_more'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Comment',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Looks like an identation issue the fields should be 1 tab inside the ProjectComment.
And can you show the migration files.

Comment: Hi @ArifRasim. Thank you for the quick response. Checked the indentation, but it does not get marked as changes. Added the initial migration file.

Comment: Did you add the first 3 fields on the model after the initial migration ? Can you run makemigrations and migrate, and see if it helps ?

Comment: @ArifRasim, I've tried to recreate it with all fields present, but this does not work either.